# jquery dialog close button not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

This is my jquery file,here "updatedata" is an external button on jsp which open this dialog1.I have a problem to close the dialog first time it close perfectly but second times gives me error.If I use default close button of dialog it also works first time then later it require multiple clikcs to close.plz help
this is my html file which is loading inside dialog1.both r separate files.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $dialog1 = $("<div></div>");
    $('#updatedata').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $dialog1.load('dialog.html').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: false,
            height: 560,
            width: 700,
            draggable: false,
            title: "Update Ship-To Information"
        }).prev().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide();
        $dialog1.dialog({
            modal: true
        });
        $dialog1.dialog("open");
        return true;
    });
    $("#image1").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var butn = $("#updatedata").prop("name");
        $.ajax({
            url: "Mediator?action=165&butn=" + butn + "&add1=" + $("#add1").val() + "&add2=" + $("#add2").val() + "&postalcode=" + $("#postalcode").val() + "&street=" + $("#street").val() + "&city=" + $("#city").val() + "&country=" + $("#country").val(),
            type: "POST",
            ContentType: false,
            success: function (msg) {
            }
        });
        alert("Form Submitted Successfully");
        location.reload(true);
        return true;
    });
    $("#image2").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        jQuery(".ui-icon-closethick").trigger('click');
    });
});
```

```html
<div id="login-box" class="login-popup">
    <form id="overrideshiptoform" class="signin">
        <div id="images" style="margin-top:20px;">
            <label id="update">Update</label>
            <Input type="image" id="image1" src="update-1.gif" value="Submit">
            <label id="CancelUpdate">Cancel Update</label>
            <Input type="image" id="image2" src="arrow.gif">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove unusual code ..

Comment: Please add code only relevant to your question.